# How is score multiplier calculated in Temple Run 2?

Tags: temple-run-2

At the end of a run, you see four things:

- Your total score
- Distance traveled
- Coins collected
- Multiplier

What is this multiplier and how can it be increased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go into the games upgrade section. Towards the bottom of the list you will find score multiplier. You have to spend coins to upgrade it. But I believe that is the solution.     ...just checked, it's under ability's and should be the last one on the bottom. (Also, if it isn't there make sure you have updated the app.)

Answer (score 3):

The multiplier is increased with two things:

- When you complete an objective.
- When you upgrade your score multiplier.

The first one is more important. It would also help you to clear levels which will result in some bonus also.